# Implementing sonarcloud SQL analyis in build pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml, sonarlint

I have a Azure DevOps build pipeline with YAML.

I want to add analysis for any SQL ad can be included here https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/languages/t-sql/

My steps are:
[image: Pipeline configuration]
using CLI

but it fails on

[image]

My pipeline so far:

steps:

## add sonar cloud lint

```
 - task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
   displayName: "Prepare analysis configuration"
   inputs:
     SonarCloud: "SonarCloudCommonDatabases" #service connection name
     organization: $(org)
     scannerMode: "CLI"
     projectKey: $(projectKey)
     projectName: $(projectName)
     # depending of your project you may need extra properties for test results, (usually for .net MVC apps)
     extraProperties: |
       # Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner, 
       # Put one key=value per line, example:
       sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*.ps1 
       sonar.exclusions=/poc
       sonar.tsql.file.suffixes=.sql
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    name: DatabaseFiles
    inputs:
      targetPath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Directory
      artifact: DB
      publishLocation: pipeline

  
  - task: SonarCloudAnalyze@1
    displayName: "Run SonarCloud analysis"
```

Comment: I would recommend to directly ask on their community website https://community.sonarsource.com/